# Setting up salt-master in Docker container: The ports are not available to bind error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, salt-stack

I'm setting up a salt-master to run in a [Docker](https://www.docker.com) container. I'm using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to build and run the container. When I start the container I get:

```
salt_master       | [WARNING ] Unable to bind socket, error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
salt_master       | The ports are not available to bind
salt_master exited with code 4
```

**– Any idea why this port cannot be bound, and how can I fix this?**

---

I'm setting the following to `/etc/salt/master`:

```
interface: 192.168.99.100
```

...since this is the IP of my `docker-machine` (I'm running [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) on OS X):

```
docker-machine ip default
> 192.168.99.100
```

Contents of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN rpm --import https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/7/x86_64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub

RUN touch /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "[saltstack-repo]" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "name=SaltStack repo for RHEL/CentOS \$releasever" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "baseurl=https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/\$releasever/\$basearch/latest" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "enabled=1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "gpgcheck=1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo
RUN echo "gpgkey=https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/\$releasever/\$basearch/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/saltstack.repo

RUN yum clean expire-cache
RUN yum update -y

RUN yum install -y virt-what
RUN yum install -y salt-master salt-minion salt-ssh salt-syndic salt-cloud


EXPOSE 4505
EXPOSE 4506
```

Contents of `docker-compose.yml`

```
image:  
  build: salt
  container_name: salt_master_image

master:
  image: saltmaster_image
  container_name: salt_master
  hostname: salt-master
  ports:
    - "4505:4505"
    - "4506:4506"
  volumes:
    - ./salt/assets/etc/salt:/etc/salt
    - ./salt/assets/var/cache/salt:/var/cache/salt
    - ./salt/assets/var/logs/salt:/var/logs/salt
    - ./salt/assets/srv/salt:/srv/salt
  command: /usr/bin/salt-master --log-file=/var/logs/salt/salt-master.log --log-file-level=debug
```

In order to build and run I execute:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

If I leave out `interface: 192.168.99.100` from `/etc/salt/master`, I don't get these errors. But then the log says `Starting the Salt Publisher on tcp://0.0.0.0:4505` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container's IP address is not `192.168.99.100`. This is the IP address of the Docker host.

The IP address of the container can be obtained by inspecting the running container: `docker inspect salt_master | grep IPAddress`. This reveals that the IP address of the container can be e.g. `172.17.0.2`.

When defining `interface 172.17.0.2` in `/etc/salt/master`, the service starts up without errors and the following can be found in the log:

```
Starting the Salt Publisher on tcp://172.17.0.2:4505
```

Since port 4505 was mapped to the Docker host, this service can now be reached through `192.168.99.100:4505`, which means that salt-minions should be able to contact the salt-master via this address, by setting `master: 192.168.99.100` in `/etc/salt/minion` on the minions.

EDIT: Since the container's IP address is bound to change, it's not safe to assume it's IP address will always be e.g. `172.17.0.2`. <s>Instead, it would be better, per @Phani's suggestion, to use `interface: 172.0.0.1` instead.</s> – turns out this doesn't work, instead use `interface: 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: You could as well do the /etc/salt/master as `interface localhost` or `interface 127.0.0.1`. That shall do the trick as well. The docker container IP address is not guaranteed to be the same every time you launch the container.

Comment: If I am not reading it wrong, you have actually mentioned the inspected IP address, which could bound to change!

Comment: You are correct. I stumbled upon this right now, as the address changed the next time I started the service! What's weird is `localhost` or `172.0.0.1` results in errors, which I find strange. However, I can leave `interface ... ` out of the `/etc/salt/master` altogether, and it seems the minion can still  find it via `192.168.99.100`.

Comment: You should use 127.0.0.1 and not 172.0.0.1! Please cross check.

Comment: Ah, yes! Typo/error on my behalf. Thank you so much for helping me solve this. `interface: 127.0.0.1` works (but `interface: localhost` does not work)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need to have the data as a separate volume in your case. Can you please change your compose file as follows and give a go

```
image:  
  build: salt
  container_name: salt_master_image

master:
  image: salt_master_image
  container_name: salt_master
  hostname: salt-master
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "4505:4505"
    - "4506:4506"
  volumes:
    - ./salt/assets/etc/salt:/etc/salt
    - ./salt/assets/var/cache/salt:/var/cache/salt
    - ./salt/assets/var/logs/salt:/var/logs/salt
    - ./salt/assets/srv/salt:/srv/salt
  command: /usr/bin/salt-master --log-file=/var/logs/salt/salt-master.log --log-file-level=debug
```

**Edited with more details:**
I would suggest you better connect to the container interactively and see what is happening inside the container. To start your docker container interactively, you should use the following command:

`docker run -it --name salt_master -p 4505:4505 -p 4506:4506 -v ./salt/assets/etc/salt:/etc/salt -v ./salt/assets/var/cache/salt:/var/cache/salt -v ./salt/assets/var/logs/salt:/var/logs/salt -v ./salt/assets/srv/salt:/srv/salt salt_master_image /bin/bash`

with the above command, you will login into the bash shell of the container, then you can execute the command manually:

`/usr/bin/salt-master --log-file=/var/logs/salt/salt-master.log --log-file-level=debug`

with this, you could understand what is going right and what is not, and accordingly you can take necessary action.

Comment: You are right, I'm editing my original question. This however, is not the source of the issue I'm experiencing, as I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: can you remove the restart: always from the compose file and run? I suppose the restart process is not doing right!

Comment: I removed it, but that doesn't make a difference. Still getting the same error but I'm now getting another error code: `salt_master exited with code 4`

Comment: I've added more details as to how to debug the situation. Please let me know if you are able to go further with this!

Comment: I'm running the container as you suggested when debugging. But I still can't figure out why I keep getting the port binding error.

Comment: did you check if there are any other services already started on the machine? it is as much possible, because in your installation step in the Dockerfile, the installation could have registered a startup script and that would have already started the process. You can find it in the container using `ps -aef`. If you find any running processes, kill them with `kill -9 PID` and then run the command.

Comment: yes, I checked. No such processes. The command in the Dockerfile is not being executed when you override its command with `/bin/bash`, like in your manual command suggestion.

Comment: If I leave out `interface: 192.168.99.100` from my `master` file, I don't get these errors. But then the log says `Starting the Salt Publisher on tcp://0.0.0.0:4505` which is not what I want.